# How to name subtotalled rows using roll up in SQL

Tags: sql-server, rollup

```
select cast(csdate as varchar(10)), 
       sum(sales)
from fact
group by rollup (datepart(year,csdate),
          datepart(week,csdate), 
          csdate)
```

Here I want the null to be replaced by the week range for that week suppose '2010-01-10 to 2010-01-12' thus for each partition's subtotal and lastly for the grandtotal as 'total'. Also I want suggestion on how can I name that row with the actual week range like in the first case, there are only two dates present for week(refer calendar) but I would like that subtotal to show with legend '2009-12-27 to 2010-01-03' representing that full week ka subtotal is this. Also, since for the first value the week is going to last year, and if I am interested to show from 1st Jan 2010, can I do that. See the existing result for reference. [image: existing result]

Comment: *"I want the null to be replace"* `ISNULL`/`COALESCE`. As for making rows, you *don't* name rows. Objects and columns have  names/aliases but rows don't.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to use the [`GROUPING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to distinguish between nulls in the data vs nulls from rollup

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use [COALESCE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwicmfHDiK-BAxXK3gIHHdlUDe0QFnoECBoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsql%2Ft-sql%2Flanguage-elements%2Fcoalesce-transact-sql%3Fview%3Dsql-server-ver16&usg=AOvVaw0q3FC99uq9Bxq5CsO3rHDm&opi=89978449), like

```
select CASE 
           WHEN grouping(datepart(year,csdate)) = 1 THEN 'year_label' 
           WHEN grouping(datepart(week,csdate)) = 1 THEN 'week_label'  
           ELSE COALESCE(cast(csdate as varchar(10)), '<yourvaluehere>')
       END
from fact
group by rollup (datepart(year,csdate),
          datepart(week,csdate), 
          csdate)
```

You have three levels of rollup: a date level, a week level and a year level due to having three levels of rollup. You need to differentiate between them.